# Defining custom parameter types with JAX-RS to return data by identifier

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am new to  Jersey, and I discovered that we can define our own parameter types to handle other types than string, as dates or boolean for instance.

I will work with an ORM to store the data in a database, so that I will be able to map an identifier to an instance of a class, let's say to a User.

Is it a good practise to define a param class which would handle the user id given in parameter (path or query for instance), and return the instance of User corresponding to the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your param is directly mappable to a primitive type then there's no need to define your own. It sounds like you want to accept a user ID as a param, which is likely to be a `long`, `int` or `String`. All of these are automatically mapped.

For example;

```
@Path("/")
public class UserService {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  @Path("/{id}")
  public User getUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    //Your implementation here
  }

}
```

Comment: Yup, and the implementation will contain the access to the database to create the actual User instance. So doing it in some mapping parameter class isn't the right way to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets take some example:

```
stackoverflow.com/users/1235336/
```

Here we have the path with usedId in it. And if we proceed the link (execute a `GET` request), we will get the some user enity in response.

So defining a user id as a path parameter and returning some user instance is kind of normal practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But is it nice to retrieve the User instance according to the user id in the parameter class or should it be done somewhere else?